# Crear una repeticion o recorrido cada ciertos datos desde un explode

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
$pal = "3,5 1401 4145 7854 8454 7458 5152556555 3,5 1401 4145 7854 8454 7458 5152556555 3,5 1401 4145 7854 8454 7458 5152556555";
$pal = explode(" ",$pal);
print_r($pal);
```

Siendo el resultado algo como esto:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3,5
    [1] => 1401
    [2] => 4145
    [3] => 7854
    [4] => 8454
    [5] => 7458
    [6] => 5152556555
    [7] => 3,5
    [8] => 1401
    [9] => 4145
    [10] => 7854
    [11] => 8454
    [12] => 7458
    [13] => 5152556555
    [14] => 3,5
    [15] => 1401
    [16] => 4145
    [17] => 7854
    [18] => 8454
    [19] => 7458
    [20] => 5152556555
)
```

Los datos de la variable $pal son ingresados desde un textbox, su contenido es algo parecido a:

```
valor  Codigo                     serial
3,5    1401 4145 7854 8454 7458   5152556555
3,5    1401 4145 7854 8454 7458   5152556555
3,5    1401 4145 7854 8454 7458   5152556555
```

Quisiera que los datos sean almacenados en una base de datos despues de hacer el explode el con la siguiente logica:

```
     // He visto por alli algo como esto:
list($valor,$codigo,$serial) = explode(" ",$pal);
    $codigo =  $pal[1] .$pal[2] .$pal[3] .$pal[4] .$pal[5];
        echo $valor; // Imprime su valor
        echo $codigo; // Imprime el codigo
        echo $serial; // Imprime el serial
```

Pero no se como lograr que sea separado el bloque de texto de la manera como lo estoy requiriendo.

Comment: Las cadenas siempre tienen el la misma longitud?? y siempre el mismo numero de argumentos, es decir `valor-Codigo-serial`??

Comment: Si siempre tendran el mismo argumento, pero logicamente cambiara el valor, ejemplo puede darse el caso de  `valor = 5   codigo =  1111 2222 3333 4444 5555   serial = 1234567890`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dado que la longitud de cada elemento puede variar pero siempre son el mismo número de elementos, la primera opción que plantee no sería válida, pero puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma.

```
<?php
$datos = "3,5 1401 4145 7854 8454 7458 5152556555 5 1401 4145 7854 8454 7458 5152556555 3,5 1401 4145 7854 8454 7458 5152556555";
// divides por espacios y cada 7 elementos, los elementos de cada fila
$temp = array_chunk(explode(' ', $datos), 7);
$ar = array();

foreach($temp as $key => $v) {
    // optienes el 1º elemento valor
    $ar[$key]['valor'] = array_shift($v);
    // optienes el ultimo elemento, serial
    $ar[$key]['serial'] = array_pop($v);
    // lo que queda es el codigo, lo unes con espacios
    $ar[$key]['codigo'] = implode(' ', $v);
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($ar);
echo '</pre>';
```

Y optener el mismo resultado:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [valor] => 3,5
            [serial] => 5152556555
            [codigo] => 1401 4145 7854 8454 7458
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [valor] => 5
            [serial] => 5152556555
            [codigo] => 1401 4145 7854 8454 7458
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [valor] => 3,5
            [serial] => 5152556555
            [codigo] => 1401 4145 7854 8454 7458
        )

)
```

---

Primera opción

Si los datos siempre tienen la misma longitud puedes cortar la cadena para estraer los fragmentos que necesites, ejemplo

```
<?php
$datos = "3,5 1401 4145 7854 8454 7458 5152556555 3,5 1401 4145 7854 8454 7458 5152556555 3,5 1401 4145 7854 8454 7458 5152556555";

$temp = str_split($datos, 40);// cortamos cada 40 caracteres
$ar = array();

// recorremos y vamos cortando cada dato individual
foreach($temp as $key => $value) {
    $ar[$key]['valor'] = substr($value, 0, 3);
    $ar[$key]['codigo'] = substr($value, 4, 24);
    $ar[$key]['serial'] = substr($value, 29, 11);
}


echo '<pre>';
print_r($ar);
echo '</pre>';
```

Resultado:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [valor] => 3,5
            [codigo] => 1401 4145 7854 8454 7458
            [serial] => 5152556555 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [valor] => 3,5
            [codigo] => 1401 4145 7854 8454 7458
            [serial] => 5152556555 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [valor] => 3,5
            [codigo] => 1401 4145 7854 8454 7458
            [serial] => 5152556555
        )

)
```

Comment: Saludos @Xerif tu ejemplo ofrecido es exactamente lo que busco pero me he encontrado ahora un nuevo reto y quisiera saber si puedes orientarme a como debo generar el `INSERT` de estos datos generados en una base de datos usando MySQLi la tabla se llama tarjetas con la siguiente estructura: `id, valor, codigo, serial` el id es autoincrement he intentado hacerlo de varias formas pense que yo solo lo lograria pero no encuentro la forma de hacerlo, puedes por favor brindarme orientacion de como debo hacerlo..?

Answer (score 2):

Esta otra variante te va a servir incluso si los códigos, valor o serial tengan longitud variable, como se muestra en la salida.

```
<?php
function string_to_array($string) {
    $len = strlen($string);
    $spc_pos = array();
    for($i=0; $i<$len; $i++) {
        if($string[$i] === ' ') {
            $spc_pos[] = $i;
        }
    }
    $offset0 = $spc_pos[0];
    $subarray[] = substr($string, 0, $offset0); // Valor
    $offset1 = $spc_pos[5] - $spc_pos[0] - 1; // La longitud del segundo string
    $subarray[] = substr($string, $spc_pos[0]+1, $offset1); // Codigo
    $subarray[] = substr($string, $spc_pos[5]+1); // Serial
    return $subarray;
}

$pal = "3,5 1401 4145 7854 8454 7458 5152556555 42,8 1401 4145 7854 8454 74585 51525555 100,32 14001 88145 78548 8454 7458 5152556555532";

$len = strlen($pal);
$start = 0;
$final_array = array();
$num_space = 0;
for($i=0; $i<$len; $i++) {
    if($pal[$i] == ' ') {
        $num_space++;
    }
    if($i == $len-1) { // Si llego al final del string
        $i++; // Para que tome el ultimo elemento
        $num_space++; // Como al final no hay espacio, se cuenta uno adicional.
    }
    if(($num_space == 7)) {
        $substring = substr($pal, $start, $i-$start);
        $final_array[] = string_to_array($substring);
        $num_space = 0;
        $start = $i+1;
    }
}

print_r($final_array);
```

Salida

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3,5
            [1] => 1401 4145 7854 8454 7458
            [2] => 5152556555
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 42,8
            [1] => 1401 4145 7854 8454 74585
            [2] => 51525555
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 100,32
            [1] => 14001 88145 78548 8454 7458
            [2] => 5152556555532
        )

)
```

Comment: Sin ofender, creo que lo complicaste demasiado, practicamente obtuve el mismo resultado en apenas 8 líneas de código. Creo que hay mucho que puedes optimizar en ese código, un saludo.

Comment: Lo que pasa @Xerif es que no conocía la función array_chunk que utilizaste. Sin esa función creeme que no te sería [[tan obvio]] dividir un string variable en substrings de igual cantidad de elementos. Tu código aparenta ser más óptimo, pero no borré el mio para dejar la referencia.

Comment: Me alegro de que almenos te sirviera para descubrir `array_chunk()`, para trocear arrays. Yo tampoco di con la solucion a la primera, de hecho la tuve que descartar en cuanto el OP proporciono mas información. Aun asi creo que te hubiese sido mas facil hecer un explode y un ciclo para contar de 7 en 7 elementos. Un saludo.

Comment: Gracias chicos, ha sido de mucha ayuda sus gentiles orientaciones, ciertamente hay muchas formas de hacer las cosas y ustedes aca dia a dia nos permiten descubrir con sus experiencias la diversidad existente.

Answer (score 0):

Esta es una manera un tanto rudimentaria de operar con lo que tienes. Al no quedarme del todo claro lo que necesitas he creado una estructura que sirve de punto de partida para hacer lo que quieras:

**PHP**

```
$pal = "3,5 1401 4145 7854 8454 7458 5152556555 3,5 1401 4145 7854 8454 7458 5152556555 3,5 1401 4145 7854 8454 7458 5152556555";
$pal = explode(" ",$pal);

$ciclo = 0;

$seriales = '';
$valores = '';
$codigos = '';

for ($i = 0; $i < count($pal); $i++) {

    if ($ciclo == 0) {
        $valores .= $pal[$i] . ' ';
    }
    else {
        if ($ciclo == 6) {
            $seriales .= $pal[$i] . ' ';
            $ciclo = -1;
        }
        else {
            $codigos .= $pal[$i] . ' ';
        }
    }

    $ciclo++;

}


echo 'Seriales son: ' . $seriales;
echo ' Valores son: ' . $valores;
echo ' Codigos son: ' . $codigos;
```

Básicamente, lo hago es crear un ciclo de 6 rotaciones, la primera rotación de cada ciclo correspondería a tus **valores**, la última a tus **seriales** y el resto serían tus **códigos**.